# Given $0\leq f(x) \leq xh(x)$ and the existence of $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\big(xh(x)\big)(0)$, can we conclude that $f'(0)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have some troubles with the following exercise. I think that it's trivial but I can't see the solution.

Let $f,h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions over $\mathbb{R}$. Given that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $$0\leq f(x)\leq xh(x)$$ and that the derivative of $xh(x)$ exists at $0$ (in fact, $\big(xh(x)\big)'(0)=h(0)$). Can we conclude that $f'(0)$ exists?

Firts, because $0\leq f(0)\leq 0h(0)=0$, we have that $f(0)=0$. Next 
$$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)-0}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}.$$
By the inequality of the hypothesis, we have $0\leq \dfrac{f(x)}{x}\leq h(x)$. Thus 
$$0\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\leq \lim\limits_{x\to 0} h(x)=h(0).$$
But then what can I do? If $h(0)=0$ the result follows. But if $h(0)>0$ I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Also, if $x$ is negative, we don't have $0\leq \frac{f(x)}{x}\leq h(x)$. Rather $0\geq\frac{f(x)}x\geq h(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. It suffices to show that $h(0)=0$.

Note that $0\leq xh(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ implies that $h(x)\geq 0$ for $x\ge0$ and $h(x)\leq 0$ for $x\le0$. Hence, since $h$ is continuous, it follows that $h(0)=0$.